# jQuery Mobile + FullCalendar - need to refresh page to see it

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Having an issue with the FullCalendar plugin for jQuery Mobile. Basically, if I load the page, the calendar doesn't know.. but if I reload the page, it does. From what I've read, it seems that on jQuery mobile only loads data inside data-role="page. If I set the link to the page as data-ajax="false", it works fine, but I want to keep ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>My Page</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/fullcalendar.css' />
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                url: 'http://google.com/'
            }
        ]
    });

});

</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a>
    <h1>My Team</h1>

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="reset.html">Reset</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->

</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">       
    <div id='calendar' style="width:100%;"></div>
</div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ZSd2C/

Never use **$(document).ready(function() {** with jQM. jQM has it own set of page handling events. In this case code is show when pageshow event was triggered:

```
$('#index').live('pageshow',function(e,data){    
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                url: 'http://google.com/'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Main problem here is document ready which triggers before jQuery Mobile page is fully loaded, like in my example it can be solved with **[pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)** event. If you want to learn more take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**

Comment: You're awesome thanks. Just started with jQuery, still trying to learn more.

Comment: actually, I do have an issue. With the above code, now the calendar shows up twice (duplicates) on the page. If I refresh, only one remains. @Gajotres

Comment: Edit: Actually, it appears that on each page creation (my index, team page) it creates another calendar. I've changed my layout to a single page with each page defined by id.

Comment: That's the problem with jQM. But it can be fixed. In your case when pageshow event is triggered check if calendar is already there. #calendar should not be empty.

Comment: Thanks again! Just did a simple check.
    if ($('#calendar').children().length == 0)

Comment: @Gajotres When I change the current date the event date will be moved to next day.How can i fix this